# Save the file for a FileField without a form

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to save the file for a `FileField` object which gets its name and content **not** from a form (but from my code). How?

I need something like:

```
field = FileField()
...
save_under_name(field, name, content_bytes)
```

How to write this function `save_under_name`?

Also I need to get the link to the saved filename.

Comment: As far as I remember you can override the save method in the model and then change the values from the record before saving

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you are most likely need to use `FieldFile` object, which defines the content of a `FileField` to save the file. To make a `FieldFile`, you could either use a file descriptor in your file system or a string representing the file content. Django doc has good explanation about `field.save()` method, quoting:

> ```
> from django.core.files import File
> # Open an existing file using Python's built-in open()
> f = open('/path/to/hello.world')
> myfile = File(f)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
> myfile = ContentFile("hello world")
> ```

Then do

```
obj.field.save('filename', myfile)
```

[Django doc says it all](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save).

Comment: What if you need to populate two FileFields?

Comment: I found the solution: FieldFile.save has a `save` parameter that defaults to `True`. Set it to `False` and once you are done assigning files, you can save the whole object with `obj.save()`.